# Django graphene GraphiQL page not loading when running from Uvicorn

Tags: graphene-django, graphiql, asgi, uvicorn

Not sure what I set wrong but I am not getting the graphiql interface when running in uvicorn using `uvicorn mysite.asgi:application`:

```
[32mINFO[0m:     Started server process [[36m14872[0m]
[32mINFO[0m:     Waiting for application startup.
[32mINFO[0m:     ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
[32mINFO[0m:     Application startup complete.
[32mINFO[0m:     Uvicorn running on [1mhttp://127.0.0.1:8000[0m (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[32mINFO[0m:     127.0.0.1:52463 - "GET /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200
Not Found: /static/graphene_django/graphiql.js
[33mWARNING[0m:  Not Found: /static/graphene_django/graphiql.js
[32mINFO[0m:     127.0.0.1:52463 - "GET /static/graphene_django/graphiql.js HTTP/1.1" 404
Not Found: /static/graphene_django/graphiql.js
[33mWARNING[0m:  Not Found: /static/graphene_django/graphiql.js
[32mINFO[0m:     127.0.0.1:52463 - "GET /static/graphene_django/graphiql.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

but it loads fine when I do `python manage.py runserver`

Here is what I have installed:

```
Python 3.8.2
Django==3.0.5
uvicorn==0.11.3
graphene==2.1.8
graphene-django==2.9.0
graphql-core==2.3.1
```

In settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]

# Graphene
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'mysite.schema.schema'
}
```

Comment: out of interest, does the endpoint still work for requests from a grapqhl client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is not serving static files by itself outside of the development server, you have to do it by yourself in some way. You can either set up a reverse proxy like nginx and instruct it to serve all the static files from your `staticfiles` directory or, **only for development**, you can instruct django to serve them, by adding to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

# Put the line provided below into your `urlpatterns` list.
url(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})
```

Make sure to use the later method only for the development, as it may have serious performance impact.

For both of the methods, you have to collect your static files as well using `python manage.py collectstatic`, as django, outside of the development server, needs all the static files to be collected in one place, your `STATIC_ROOT`.

Answer (score 3):

Just set DEBUG = True in your settings.py file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Sometimes its the simplest of things that are overlooked. You helped me not spend hours on figuring this out. :D

Comment: Not at all! You are welcome.